# Do we need MacTex for Lyx on Mac?

Tags: macos, latex

MacTex is apparently 4+GB to install. It says on the Lyx downloads that MacTex is a necessary dependency.

https://www.lyx.org/Download

Do we really need MacTex?

Comment: I can't imagine they'd tell you it was needed if it wasn't.

Comment: Well is it necessary for all features of Lyx or just some features? that's another Q

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by the question:

*Do we really need MacTeX *specifically*?* - No, you do not need MacTex specifically. You could in theory use other LaTeX distributions or install LaTeX yourself. MacTeX is just an easy and convenient way to get a full LaTeX system running on your Mac.

*Do we really need TeX at all?* - Yes, you do need a working TeX system in order to produce documents. As soon as you want to render the document, print it, or similar, you will need TeX - and LyX alone won't suffice.